# Lucene.Net IndexWriter bug

Tags: c#, lucene, .net-4.5, lucene.net

I noticed that indexwriter is delete all files in index folder while it was opening. When I traced code,I saw that segment files wasn't committed after indexwriter.close() event.

This is a bug ? Or I need to configure indexwriter ?(Lucene 3.03)

```
     public IndexWriter iw_global { get; set; }
            ...
            RAMDirectory idx = new RAMDirectory();
            IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(idx, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
            iw.UseCompoundFile = true;

            List<Document> docs = new List<Document>();

            #region Index Ekle
            foreach (var link in linkList)
            {
                Document docx = new Document();
                //docx.Add(new NumericField("id", Field.Store.YES, true).SetLongValue(link.id));
                docx.Add(new Field("id", link.id.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

                //docx.Add(new NumericField("index_tarih", Field.Store.YES, true).SetLongValue(link.index_tarih.Ticks));
                docx.Add(new Field("index_tarih", link.index_tarih.Ticks.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
                iw.AddDocument(docx);
            }
           iw.Commit();
           this.iw_global.AddIndexesNoOptimize(idx);
           .......
           iw.Dispose();
           idx.Dispose();
```

Opens iw_global,

```
private void MasterIndexOpen()
        {
            DirectoryInfo dirAktif = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(ConfigFile.ConfigsPaths["MasterIndex"], this.courrent_date.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")));
            if (!dirAktif.Exists)
                dirAktif.Create();
            FileInfo LockFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dirAktif.FullName,"write.lock"));
            if (LockFile.Exists)
                LockFile.Delete();
            Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory lcneFolder = Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.Open(dirAktif);


            FileInfo fiAktifYes = new FileInfo(string.Format("{0}\\Yes.txt", dirAktif.FullName));

            this.iw_global = new IndexWriter(lcneFolder, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30), !fiAktifYes.Exists, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
            this.iw_global.Commit();
            this.iw_global.UseCompoundFile = true;

            if (!fiAktifYes.Exists)
                fiAktifYes.Create();
        }
```

Comment: Your code seems to have two writers, `iw` and `iw_global`. You're not showing how you are opening the `iw_global`instance.

Comment: yes I have two writers,one of them writes data to ramdirectory,and other writes ramdirectory to disk. Shouldn't be a aproblem ?

Comment: Your code doesn't do that. Your code writes to both `iw` and `iw_global`, while the problem you describe related to the opening of the IndexWriter seems to be located in MasterIndexOpen, code which isn't shown. Why are you writing to an in-memory directory and not directly to disk?

Comment: @SimonSvensson iw writes to only memory,iw_global writes to disk. I am writing to an memory directory, because i have to work with higest possible performance.

Comment: Have you taken any measures to determine what's slowing down? The http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveIndexingSpeed page mentions the compound file format. Your code calls both `iw` and `iw_global` which means that it will still perform when calling only `iw_global`. Anyhow, you still havn't shown us what `MasterIndexOpen` does. Any reason why you don't use Directory.Copy to write your in-memory directory to disk?

Comment: And now the code was edited to work very differently (using AddIndexesNoOptimize instead of AddDocument), but you're still missing the method that you're actually asking about, the method that opens your IndexWriter causing your index directory to be emptied.

Comment: @SimonSvensson yes ,I have written wrong code before. The problem occurs current edited code. Sorry.

Comment: I am still waiting for the row of code that opens your global IndexWriter, you've only shown the row which opens your in-memory writer.

Comment: I wrote how i open iw_global.

Comment: Why are you removing the lock-file, if present? Why are you using a custom Yes.txt-file instead of IndexReader.Exists? Why are you using compound files when you state that performance is important to you? http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveIndexingSpeed

Comment: @SimonSvensson firstly thank you for your interesting. I don't remember why I handle lock-file and yes.txt file. And I think it isn't be reason of the problem. I am using compound file because it is necessary. Summary of my work :  I work just on new data. When a new data is added to my sistem,I add it to ram directory. And then I process it in-ram-directory. So I only process new data. After that I add in-ram-directory to disk directory. Therefore I work with less data with higer performance and I always access past data in disk directory.

Comment: I would rewrite your current solution to use only default options (no messing with the lock file, use IndexReader.Exist instead of Yes.txt, don't use compund files, etc) and look into near-real-time searching with Lucene. You can call IndexWriter.GetReader to get a reader that are able to access content (and thus search) that has not yet been committed.